# IE 11 Temporary Internet Files Disk Space set to 0 and would not change

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, diskcache

Not so much a question as the issue I think has been solved

I had a user ring me today when an application on our network would freeze before the users application menu appeared after they had logged in. It just did not appear.

After a bit of digging here and there and using the developer tools in IE11 (F12) and looking at the network trace on the browser I noticed that the GET's on some of the directories were being aborted. Further head scratching at this point so I looked at the Internet Options Temporary Internet File cache size and noted it was set to zero. No amount of trying would change it.

These PC's are locked down and have encryption software on but I could run the application as the PC Admin and when I did this low and behold the cache size was the default 1024Mb and the menus appeared. Run as the normal user and no disk space, no menus.

Conclusion was that because there was no disk available the gets were unable to download to the temp internet files area.

In this case the fix is going to be re-imaging the PC concerned but I wondered if anyone else had come across this problem and had any other fixes for it. Editing the registry did not seem to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting the same issue in our firm environment. I believe this is due to a MS software update but not sure which one is the culprit.

A workaround is to delete the temporary internet files folder not just clearing the files within the folder but actually deleting the folder. There is a file in there called counters.dat which is the culprit.

Comment: Thanks Rene we will investigate that further and add it to our list of fixes.